# DTM Events are not reflecting in dashboard with new SDK version 4.x

Tags: ios, dashboard, adobe-analytics

I have used Omniture/DTM latest SDK in my iOS application, I have followed the [migration document provided by marketing.adobe.com](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mobile/ios/migration_v3.html), and all logs are requesting to Adobe server as per our requirements - but events, page views and purchase items are not reflecting in the Omniture dashboard.

Comment: are you seeing *any* data show up?  If not, my first guess would be you have the request setup for offline tracking but pointing to a report suite that does not have it enabled.  Or the opposite: the report suite is setup for offline tracking but your app isn't setup for offline tracking (so the timestamp param isn't included)

Comment: I have tried both cases but, still data's are not appears in dashboard.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are specifying the proper report suite id (rsid) in your code? Are you looking in that same report suite in the interface?  Have you checked that you are pointing to the proper collection server?

Comment: I have verified rsid in code and interface and its same.

Comment: And the tracking server too? If you have indeed verified that all of this is correct and that you are seeing the request sent to Adobe then honestly I can't think of any other reason you shouldn't see any data come in at all, not even base hits.  Sounds like you should contact Adobe ClientCare. Maybe there is an issue with the tracking server on their end or maybe the hit cap for your account has been reached or something.